# Question about operator precedence for in and !=

Tags: python

While writing Python code, I got a result different from what I wanted.

```py
>>> temp = [1]
>>> 1 in temp != 2 in temp
False
>>> (1 in temp) != (2 in temp)
True
>>> ((1 in temp) != 2) in temp
True
```

My purpose was the second, but I wrote it like the first.

The problem has been solved, but I wonder in what order the first expression outputs `False`.

I wondered if it was because of the same principle as the third, but the third also outputs `True`.

Comment: Why don't you search for "python operator precedence"?

Comment: @Julien I think this is operator chaining, not operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is caused by operator chaining.

In Python, you can write an expression with two (or more) operators like this:

```
a < b < c
```

And Python treats this as if you wrote `(a < b) and (b < c)`.

So Python is treating your expression

```
1 in temp != 2 in temp
```

As if you wrote:

```
(1 in temp) and (temp != 2) and (2 in temp)
```

Which is false.